# Incorrect Information on College Scorecard

Tags: collegescorecard

I am the Marketing Communications Director at a college listed on your website, and much of the information is incorrect (enrollment, academic programs, and costs are listed as including room and board and are not stated as such). How can we revise this information to make it more accurate?

Comment: @lisabalid this is a forum used for many diverse open data quesions. Please note that it is not specifically related to College Scorecard.

Comment: i agree with you completely @philshem but there's no way for users not familiar with se to know that. this is an example of why i made that post in meta...

Answer (score 4):

I work on the Scorecard for the Department of Education.  We can examine cases in which some data may appear incorectly.   Could you provide examples of specific institutions and statistics that may be appearing incorrectly?

Also, you can submit specific questions and suggestions about data to scorecarddata@rti.org. We will be tracking input and refining the website iteratively.

Answer (score 1):

Please also note that most of the data are generated through IPEDS and NSLDS and each of those have existing mechanisms in place.  Updates would then be reflected in future Scorecard updates.

Answer (score 0):

This site is an public discussion on open data issues. You can respond directly to a question related to the data from your university with a comment or an answer to the question. This would allow you to correct information if you have open data to support the correction.

If someone references an underlying dataset (like College Scorecard) that you believe has erroneous information, please contact that data owner directly as Stack Exchange does not manage that type of data.  Thanks!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thanks for the note @albert. The question is how to correct data that is mentioned on the site.  This answer responds to the question of how to do that, and adds to the clarifying note from philshem that SE does not provide the data, but rather links to the data.

Comment: i know you know the rules, so sorry if that was annoying. still not 100% on how to handle this....

Comment: Appreciate your participation and insights. The site only gets better when we all work to correct and vote up (and down) the answers.  Thanks!